# Having difficulty printing text from php function on html page

Tags: php, html

Here's an example of what I have going on:

common.php

```
<?php
class Common {
    function test() {
        echo 'asdf;
    }
}?>
```

webpage.php

```
<?php 
require_once("common.php");
?>

<html>
<body>
    <?php test(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

No matter what I've tried, I cannot get the function test to print any text to the page. With the actual webpage I was using, anything below the '' line didn't load with that portion included. I've been searching around for the past hour to figure this out, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you don't have a function. You have a method in a class. You never instantiate that class or call the method. You're trying to call an undefined FUNCTION. `$foo = new Common; $foo->test()` is what you're missing. And since you don't mention getting a "fatal error: call to undefined function" error, you're undoubtedly working with error_reporting and display_errors turned off. they should NEVER be off on a devel/debug system.

Answer (score 3):

You have missing a ' closure also dont need a class for this, you should have just the function definition

```
<?php
function test() {
    echo 'asdf';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
class Common {
     function test() {
        echo 'asdf'; // missing a ' closure added
    }
}?>
```

You can access this function using a object of this class

```
<?php 
require_once("common.php");

// instantiate the class before you use it.

$common = new Common(); // Common is a object of class Common
?>

<html>
<body>
    <?php echo $common->test(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, If you don't want to have a `$common` variable you can make the method static like this.

```
<?php
class Common {
    static function test() {
        echo 'asdf';
    }
}?>
```

Then all you have to do to call the method is:

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php echo Common::test(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: dminones answer is also valid. Judging by the names used, this was only test code and not the actual intended use. It really depends what you are trying to achieve.